# Can I use a WHERE clause and still use SQLCommandBuilder?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, ado.net

I wanted to be able to do the below, but not sure if SQLCommandBulder will blow up. (I DON'T have all my code setup to test it yet).

```
Dim renameFileCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from FileVersions where vpk = @vpk", sqlConn)
renameFileCmd.Parameters.Add("@vpk", SqlDbType.BigInt)
renameFileCmd.Parameters.Item(0).Value = vpk
renameFileCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim renameFileAdptr As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(renameFileCmd)
Dim renameFileBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(renameFileAdptr)
Dim renameFileDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable
renameFileAdptr.Fill(renameFileDataTable)
```

Comment: I meant I don't have all my code setup to test it.... oops.

Comment: I just started writing it. And I don't have the GUI setup and the data depends on other data (and code) that I don't know have flushed out yet. And there's no data in the DB, because it's just newly created.

Comment: Yes, a simple SELECT ... FROM ... WHERRE ... should be Ok for the CommandBuilder. No joins etc. And SELECT * is always a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you want to put that as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept/mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Henk Holterman. Using a simple Where clause is acceptable for a SqlCommandBuilder.